# iOS throttling async API calls using NSBlockOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsoperationqueue, nsblockoperation

I want to limit the number of inflight API calls to 2.  I can create an `NSOperationQueue` and add the block to the queue, however each API call has a completion block, so the initial calls are limited but I don't know how to limit the processing of the queue based on the execution of the completion block.

In the code below it is possible to have more than 2 calls APIs in flight at anyone time.

```
NSOperationQueue *requestQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
service.requestQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        [self invokeAPI:kAPIName completion:^BOOL(APIResult *result) {

            // Do stuff
        }

         [requestQueue addOperation:operation];
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any pointers to the correct pattern to use.

**EDIT - Based on Marc-Alexandre's answer**

Have created this class to encapsulate the operations, is the approach safe from a memory point of view, given that this class will be created from the dataAccessService and injected, as well as the completion block having references to self, and the finish called ***before*** the completion block executes?

```
@interface MAGApiOperation : NSOperation

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MAGDataAccessServiceProtocol> dataAccessService;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *apiName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) BOOL (^onCompletion)(APIResult *);

+ (instancetype)apiOperationWithName:(NSString *)apiName dataAccessService:(id<MAGDataAccessServiceProtocol>)dataAccessService completion:(BOOL (^)(APIResult *))onCompletion;

@implementation MAGApiOperation

@synthesize executing = _isExecuting;
@synthesize finished = _isFinished;

#pragma mark - Class methods

/// Creates a new instance of MAGApiOperation
+ (instancetype)apiOperationWithName:(NSString *)apiName dataAccessService:(id<MAGDataAccessServiceProtocol>)dataAccessService completion:(BOOL (^)(APIResult *))onCompletion {

    MAGApiOperation *operation = [[self alloc] init];
    operation.apiName = apiName;
    operation.dataAccessService = dataAccessService;
    operation.onCompletion = onCompletion;

    return operation;
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation method overrides

- (void)start {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    if (!self.isCancelled)
    {
        [self invokeApiWithName:self.apiName completion:self.onCompletion];
    }
}

- (void)finish {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

/// Invokes the api with the name then executes the completion block
- (void)invokeApiWithName:(NSString *)apiName completion:(BOOL (^)(VAAInvokeAPIResult *))onCompletion {

        [self.dataAccessService invokeAPI:kAPIName completion:^BOOL(APIResult *result) { {

            [self finish];

            return onCompletion(result);
        }];
}
```

Comment: From your code, it will not have more than 2 API calls in parallel at any time.

Comment: The NSOperation does have a completionBlock already that you can use. you don't need to implement your own. Instead, just store result in a `@property`, and then when invoking your operation do this: myOperation.completionBlock = ^{ /* Here you have access to myOperation.results */ }. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass NSOperation in order to do that.

Here's the full documentation that explains it all how to subclass NSOperation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation

Quick notes:

- Your "start" operation would be the `invokeAPI` call.
- Then in your invokeAPI completion block, you mark your own operation as finished (see below, note the willChange and didChange calls are really important)

---

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
self.isExecuting = NO;
self.isFinished = YES;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
```

Comment: Thank Marc, appreciate it.  Have amended the question to include a subclass of NSOperation, would appreciate any comments re: possible memory leaks or bad access.